# Sorting UTF-8 strings in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, utf-8

I am trying to figure out a 'proper' way of sorting UTF-8 strings in Ruby on Rails.

In my application, I have a select box that is populated with countries. As my application is localized, each existing locale has a countries.yml file that relates a country's id to the localized name for that country. I can't sort the strings manually in the yml file because I need the ID to be consistent across all locales.

What I have done is create a `ascii_name` method which uses the [`unidecode`](http://rubyforge.org/projects/unidecode/) gem to convert accented and non-latin characters to their ascii equivalent (for instance, "Afeganistão" would become "Afeganistao"), and then sort on that:

```
require 'unidecode'

class Country
  def ascii_name
    Unidecoder.decode(name).gsub("[?]", "").gsub(/`/, "'").strip
  end
end

Country.all.sort_by(:&ascii_name)
```

However, there are obvious issues with this:

- It cannot properly sort non-latin locales, as there may not be a direct analogous latin character.
- It makes no distinction between a letter and all accented forms of that letter (so, for instance, A and Ä become interchangeable)

Does anyone know of a better way that I could sort my strings?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

http://github.com/grosser/sort_alphabetical

This gem should help. It adds `sort_alphabetical` and `sort_alphabetical_by` methods to Enumberable.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly the sort of plugin I was looking for!

Comment: This plugin relies on NFD decomposition http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence#Normal_forms and fails in some cases. Not all diacritic characters can be decomposed this way (for example Polish letter Ł can not).

Comment: @skalee Do you have any suggestion how to properly sort utf-8 strings with polish characters?

Comment: @acidburn2k If you are grabbing records from database, you probably want to fetch them sorted by db engine. See documentation for your RDBS and search for "collation". You can set collation you like the most for whole database, table or (AFAIR) even specify it in your query. In MySQL, the best collation for Polish is `utf8_polish_ci`. If you want to sort them in Ruby, follow this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5472046/304175

Answer (score 11):

Ruby peforms string comparisons based on byte values of characters:

```
%w[à a e].sort
# => ["a", "e", "à"]
```

To properly collate strings according to locale, the [ffi-icu](https://github.com/jarib/ffi-icu) gem could be used:

```
require "ffi-icu"

ICU::Collation.collate("it_IT", %w[à a e])
# => ["a", "à", "e"]

ICU::Collation.collate("de", %w[a s x ß])
# => ["a", "s", "ß", "x"]
```

As an alternative:

```
collator = ICU::Collation::Collator.new("it_IT")
%w[à a e].sort { |a, b| collator.compare(a, b) }
# => %w[a à e]
```

**Update** To test how strings should collate according to locale rules the ICU project provides [this nice tool](http://demo.icu-project.org/icu-bin/locexp?_=root&d_=en&x=col).

Comment: The only thing I don't like about "ffi-icu" is that it depends on "libicu". But I guess this is pretty ubiquitous on UNIX systems, right?

Comment: Usually it is not installed by default, but it is available on almost any system.

Comment: So, can we say that ruby (2.7, at least) sorts strings in POSIX/C ?

Answer (score 4):

The only solution I have found thus far is to use `ActiveSupport::Inflector.transliterate(string)` to replace the unicode characters with ASCII ones and sort:

```
Country.all.sort_by do |country|
  ActiveSupport::Inflector.transliterate country.name
end
```

Now the only problem is that this equalizes "ä" with "a" (DIN 5007-1) and I end up with "Ägypten" before "Albanien" while I would expect it to be the other way around. Thankfully the transliteration is configurable about how to replace characters.

See documentation: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-transliterate

Comment: Are you just looking for a method to transliterate strings or a method to sort strings according to a locale collation?

Comment: The latest, sort strings by a locale collation.

Comment: Even with proper collation (I supposed `de_DE.UFT8`) it is normal that *Ägypten* comes before *Albanien*.

Comment: I know, but with the Austrian collation, I think "A" < "Ä" < "B". And `ActiveSupport::Inflector` does not support it by default.

Comment: See [this](http://demo.icu-project.org/icu-bin/locexp?_=de_AT&d_=en&x=col), you can test how strings are sorted depending on collation.

Comment: ActiveSupport::Inflector.transliterate helped me, thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to go. You may want to convert the UTF strings to hex strings and then sort them:

```
s.split(//).collect { |x| x.unpack('U').to_s }.join
```

or you may use the library iconv. Read up on it and use it as appropriate (from dzone):

```
#add this to environment.rb
#call to_iso on any UTF8 string to get a ISO string back
#example : "Cédez le passage aux français".to_iso

class String
  require 'iconv' #this line is not needed in rails !
  def to_iso
    Iconv.conv('ISO-8859-1', 'utf-8', self)
  end
end
```

Comment: Hm, sorting by the hex value does seem to put my strings in the alphabetical order, but I don't really understand how it's working, can you explain that? Also, it's still sorting Á before A, which seems backwards to me.

Comment: Also watch out: Unicode sorting depends on the locale! Different countries have a different order in their dictionary.

Comment: Well, converting to hex gives you an ordering that is better understood by sort functions. I would experiment a bit, by using hex values formatted to 2 or 3 decimal places. or even use decimal values for each character. I am not a big UTF user myself, but it appears from Rutger's comments that what you are trying to do does not have an exact answer.

Comment: @Rutger that's what I'm trying to figure out how to implement, I guess, and is another downfall of my current method (or sorting by character code)

Answer (score 1):

The only working solution I found so far (at least for Ruby 1.8 because Ruby 1.9 should handle Unicode better) is [Unicode by Yoshida Masato](http://github.com/blackwinter/unicode). You can find Unicode.strcmp method there.

**EDIT:** Sorry, this solution uses NFD decomposition as well with all its limitations.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is a very messy proposition. There is no way to do transparent transliteration on all Unicode characters because the meaning of digraphs changes from locale to locale, and strings can grow HUGE (if say you replace 10 Chinese symbols with theyr phonetic equivalents). Don't go there.

Why do you want transliterated names in the first place? For URLs? Browsers handle Unicode URLs decently now, so you are inventing a huge problem out of thin air. If you need IDs, preprocess your lists to include a stable numeric ID per country and use that as an identifier. Or save the English name of the country as identitifer (you can download locale-aware ISO country lists for free).

If you truly want good transliteration for Unicode (and this is not what you want in this case) see the IBM ICU libraries, there is a dormant gem for them.

Comment: Question clearly asks about sorting of localized strings. Not about a transliteration.

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried accessing the `mb_chars` method for each of your country strings? `mb_chars` is a proxy that ActiveSupport adds that defines Unicode safe versions of all the `String` methods. If the comparator is Unicode-aware then the sorting should work correctly.

- [`mb_chars` documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/String/Multibyte.html#M001322)

Comment: The problem with using mb_chars is the same as sorting straight; because in the character set A-Z comes before Ä, accented characters will not sort into the correct location.