# Ruby, advanced array sorting

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have the following array of arrays:

```
[
  ["Częstochowa", "Częstochowa"], 
  ["Jaworzno", "Jaworzno"], 
  ["Katowice", "Katowice"], 
  ["Nowy Dwór Mazowiecki", "Nowy Dwór Mazowiecki"], 
  ["Ożarowice", "Ożarowice"],
  ["Katowice Airport", "Ożarowice"], 
  ["Raszków", "Raszków"], 
  ["Sosnowiec", "Sosnowiec"], 
  ["Tarnowskie Góry", "Tarnowskie Góry"], 
  ["Warszawa", "Warszawa"], ["Katowice, Airport Ożarowice"], 
  ["Warszawa, Airport Modlin", "Nowy Dwór Mazowiecki"], 
  ["Warszawa, Airport Okęcie", "Warszawa"]
]
```

Now I want to sort that when we have `["Katowice", "Katowice"]` the next one is `["Katowice Airport" "Ożarowice"]`. Is there any way do to this?

Comment: so you want them to be in alphabetical order?

Comment: you want them in what order?

Comment: I made a minor edit, to make the data more visible. However, your two mentions of `Katowice Airport` are different and neither is valid Ruby. Please fix that, it makes the question hard to understand (we need to know whether "Airport" is in the first or second string).

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly, a simple [`sort`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-sort) would do:

```
arr.sort
# => [["Częstochowa", "Częstochowa"], ["Jaworzno", "Jaworzno"], 
#     ["Katowice", "Katowice"], ["Katowice, Airport", "Ożarowice"], 
#     ["Nowy Dwór Mazowiecki", "Nowy Dwór Mazowiecki"], 
#     ["Ożarowice", "Ożarowice"], ["Raszków", "Raszków"], 
#     ["Sosnowiec", "Sosnowiec"], ["Tarnowskie Góry", "Tarnowskie Góry"], 
#     ["Warszawa", "Warszawa"], ["Warszawa, Airport Modlin", "Nowy Dwór Mazowiecki"],
#     ["Warszawa, Airport Okęcie", "Warszawa"]]
```

When sorting an array of arrays, the `sort`'s default behavior is to sort by the first element, using the second element as a tie-breaker.

Comment: This works but only when in strings i not have Polish special characters on the beginning like: "Ł". When I have Łódź city it is automatically on the end of list...

Comment: @Mateusz Urbański: That is a different question. (Although a lot more interesting than your original question, which essentially becomes "Q. How do I sort? A. Use `.sort`."

Comment: @MateuszUrbański - see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/982948/sorting-utf-8-strings-in-ror - it suggests using a gem - https://github.com/grosser/sort_alphabetical/tree/master

Comment: @UriAgassi didn't know about the tie-breaker, that's good to know, thanks!  OP, I just implemented a sorter for non-standard characters - it was a bit of a pain, but it's very possible.  A gem might not be a bad choice though.

Answer (score 1):

Note that in your question `["Katowice, Airport "Ożarowice"]` is not valid - I changed it to `["Katowice, Airport", "Ożarowice"]` as that seems to fit the pattern in your other arrays

```
a = [
  ["Częstochowa", "Częstochowa"], 
  ["Jaworzno", "Jaworzno"], 
  ["Katowice", "Katowice"], 
  ["Nowy Dwór Mazowiecki", "Nowy Dwór Mazowiecki"], 
  ["Ożarowice", "Ożarowice"], 
  ["Raszków", "Raszków"], 
  ["Sosnowiec", "Sosnowiec"], 
  ["Tarnowskie Góry", "Tarnowskie Góry"], 
  ["Warszawa", "Warszawa"], ["Katowice, Airport", "Ożarowice"], 
  ["Warszawa, Airport Modlin", "Nowy Dwór Mazowiecki"], 
  ["Warszawa, Airport Okęcie", "Warszawa"]
]
a.sort_by { |element| element.first }
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer for my question is:

```
sort_by{|x| ActiveSupport::Inflector.transliterate(x[0])}
```

Thanks everyone for help.

Comment: If this is correct, then could you please re-phrase your question, so that this answer matches it? There is nothing in your question about handling inflections.