# Sort non-latin strings in Ruby

Tags: ruby, sorting, dictionary, alphabetical, alphabetical-sort

OK, so what I need is rather self-explanatory.

The same way `.sort` is used, in order to alphabetically/lexicographically sort an array of latin-based string, I'm looking for a way to sort non-latin UTF-8 strings.

**Specifically:**

- Cyrillic
- Greek
- Chinese
- Japanese
- Armenian
- Thai
- Georgian
- Hebrew
- Arabic

And by "sorting", I mean the very same way you would normally find them in a dictionary. (I know it can be a lot trickier for chinese/japanese, so let's just stick to the rest of them first)

Any ideas?

---

P.S. I'm not interested in transliteration (that's what I'm currently doing), as the results are very far from "correct" - lexicographically speaking...

---

Note: It's not RoR-related. Just pure Ruby.

Comment: Have you tried [sort_alphabetical](https://github.com/grosser/sort_alphabetical)?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Well, from what I'm seeing, this one does some sort of transliteration too, nope?

Comment: Where do you see that? As far as I know, it sorts using some unicode voodoo.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Hm, hm, hm... Looks like you are right. Just did a quick test with a greek wordlist, and ... boom! (I'm Greek, so I can easily tell whether it works or not...). Let's see... time to start trying different scripts... :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting UTF-8 strings in RoR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/982948/sorting-utf-8-strings-in-ror)

Answer (score 5):

As you note, [Unicode collation](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr10/) is tricky stuff - you almost certainly don't want to be doing it yourself.

The daddy of Unicode handling library is icu. There are quite a lot of ruby bindings for icu, many of which look rather old, but [ffi-icu](https://github.com/jarib/ffi-icu) seems reasonably active.

Twitter also maintain [twitter-cldr-rb](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-cldr-rb) which claims to have a pure ruby full implementation of the Unicode collation algorithm.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll have a look into it! :)

Comment: twitter-cldr-rb is pretty awesome, I recommend it. It should do what you need.