# How one should add UTF-8 support to sorting in Ruby (including ł character, without affecting portability)?

Tags: ruby, sorting, utf-8, portability

Ruby string functions are not supporting UTF-8.

For example `['l', 'ł', 'm'].sort` returns `["l", "m", "ł"]` rather than `["l", "ł", "m"]`.

How one should sort UTF-8 strings in Ruby?

[Sorting UTF-8 strings in RoR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982948/sorting-utf-8-strings-in-ror) - accepted answer has no support for ł character ([issue open since 2015](https://github.com/grosser/sort_alphabetical/issues/13), blocked by [PR waiting opened in 2014](https://github.com/lang/unicode_utils/pull/10)), waiting unmerged as of 2017-10-08.

[ffi-icu answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982948/sorting-utf-8-strings-in-ror/17173122#17173122) works for systems that have libicu installed what AFAIK is not really portable.

Comment: I am aware of no good solution save for [`unicode`](https://github.com/blackwinter/unicode) gem.

Comment: @mudasobwa In my test it failed `require "unicode" puts ['l', 'ł', 'm'].sort{|a, b| Unicode::strcmp(a, b)} puts ['l', 'ł', 'm'].sort{|a, b| Unicode::strcmp_compat(a, b)}` (based on documentation from https://github.com/blackwinter/unicode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

good solution is using gem https://github.com/twitter/twitter-cldr-rb

```
require 'twitter_cldr'
collator = TwitterCldr::Collation::Collator.new
collator.sort(['m', 'ł', 'l'])
=> ["l", "ł", "m"]
```

Comment: `['m', 'ł', 'l'].localize(:pl).sort.to_a` also works and it is shorter. Also, it explicitly sets localization.

Comment: Also, [from readme](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-cldr-rb#requirements): "No external requirements."