# Sorting in Ruby using the Unicode collation algorithm

Tags: ruby, postgresql, unicode, collation

Ruby and Postgres are sorting slightly differently and this is causing subtle problems in my project. There's two issues: accented characters and spaces. It looks like Ruby is sorting ASCII-betically and Postgres is sorting with the proper [Unicode collation algorithm](http://unicode.org/reports/tr10/#Merging_Sort_Keys).

Heroku Postgres 11.2. Database collation is `en_US.UTF-8`.

```
psql (11.3, server 11.2 (Ubuntu 11.2-1.pgdg16.04+1))
...
=> select 'quia et' > 'qui qui';
 ?column? 
----------
 f
(1 row)
=> select 'quib' > 'qüia';
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

Ruby 2.4.4 on Heroku.

```
Loading production environment (Rails 5.2.2.1)
[1] pry(main)> 'quia et' > 'qui qui'
=> true
[2] pry(main)> 'quib' > 'qüia'
=> false
[3] pry(main)> ENV['LANG']
=> "en_US.UTF-8"
```

I can fix the handling of accented characters, but I can't get Ruby to do spaces correctly. For example, here's how they sort the same list.

```
Postgres: ["hic et illum", "quia et ipsa", "qui qui non"]
Ruby:     ["hic et illum", "qui qui non", "quia et ipsa"]
```

I've tried the [`icunicode` gem](https://github.com/ninjudd/icunicode):

```
array.sort_by {|s| s.unicode_sort_key}
```

This handles accented characters, but does not do spaces correctly.

How do I get Ruby to sort using the Unicode collation algorithm?

**UPDATE** A more comprehensive example is found in [Unicode® Technical Standard #10](http://unicode.org/reports/tr10/#Merging_Sort_Keys). These are in the correct order.

```
  [
    "di Silva   Fred",
    "diSilva    Fred",
    "disílva    Fred",
    "di Silva   John",
    "diSilva    John",
    "disílva    John"
  ]
```

Comment: Maybe try [icu4r](http://web.archive.org/web/2019/http://icu4r.rubyforge.org/classes/UCollator.html)?

Comment: @daxim That's 11 years old. But I did try [with `ffi-icu` from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17173122/14660). It only seems to get part of the algorithm right, it doesn't handle spaces. `["di Silva Fred", "di Silva John", "diSilva Fred", "disílva Fred", "diSilva John", "disílva John"]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does your use case allow for simply delegating the sorting to Postgres, rather than trying to recreate it in Ruby?

Part of the difficultly here is that there isn't a *single* correct sorting method, but any variable elements can result in fairly large discrepancies in the final sort order e.g. see [the section on variable weighting](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr10/tr10-38.html#Variable_Weighting).

For example, a gem like [twitter-cldr-rb](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-cldr-rb#sorting-collation) has a fairly robust implementation of the UCA, and is backed by a comprehensive test suite - but against the non-ignorable test cases, which is different from the Postgres implementation (Postgres appears to use the shift-trimmed variant).

The sheer number of [test cases](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UCA/11.0.0/CollationTest.html) means that you have no guarantee that one working solution will match the Postgres sort order *in all cases*. E.g. will it handle en/em dash correctly, or even emojis? You could fork and modify the `twitter-cldr-rb` gem, but I suspect this won't be a small undertaking!

If you need to handle values that don't exist in the database, you can ask Postgres to sort them in a lightweight fashion by using a `VALUES` list:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('de luge'),('de Luge'),('de-luge'),('de-Luge'),('de-luge'),('de-Luge'),('death'),('deluge'),('deLuge'),('demark')) AS t(term) ORDER BY term ASC"
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql).values.flatten
```

It will obviously result in a round-trip to Postgres, but should be very speedy nonetheless.

Comment: Interesting. The current use case testing that the UI is providing sorted results. The sorting is done by PG, but checked by Ruby. I only care that it's sorting by a particular field, the exact details don't matter. I'll give this a shot.

Comment: This ended up being a fantastically useful suggestion. We have a lot of tests that compare the sort order of an api response with the sort order of an array of strings. Using ruby .sort was causing all kinds of flakes. Implementing the above in a spec helper alleviated a lot of false test failures!

Answer (score 5):

I got very close using this algorithm with the [icunicode gem](https://github.com/ninjudd/icunicode).

```
require 'icunicode'

def database_sort_key(key)
  key.gsub(/\s+/,'').unicode_sort_key
end

array.sort_by { |v|
  [database_sort_key(v), v.unicode_sort_key]
}
```

First we sort using the unicode sort key with whitespace removed. Then if those are the same we sort by the unicode sort key of the original value.

This works around a weakness in `unicode_sort_key`: it doesn't consider spaces to be weak.

```
2.4.4 :007 > "fo p".unicode_sort_key.bytes.map { |b| b.to_s(16) }
 => ["33", "45", "4", "47", "1", "8", "1", "8"] 
2.4.4 :008 > "foo".unicode_sort_key.bytes.map { |b| b.to_s(16) }
 => ["33", "45", "45", "1", "7", "1", "7"]
```

Note that the space in `fo p` is as important as any other character. This results in `'fo p' < 'foo'` which is incorrect. We work around this by first stripping out spaces before generating the key.

```
2.4.4 :011 > "fo p".gsub(/\s+/, '').unicode_sort_key.bytes.map { |b| b.to_s(16) }
 => ["33", "45", "47", "1", "7", "1", "7"] 
2.4.4 :012 > "foo".gsub(/\s+/, '').unicode_sort_key.bytes.map { |b| b.to_s(16) }
 => ["33", "45", "45", "1", "7", "1", "7"]
```

Now `'foo' < 'fo p'` which is correct.

But because of the normalization we might have values which appear to be the same after whitespace has been stripped, `fo o` should be less than `foo`. So if the `database_sort_key`s are the same, we compare their plain `unicode_sort_key`s.

There's a few edge cases where it's wrong. `foo` should be less than `fo o` but this gets it backwards.

Here's it is as `Enumerable` methods.

```
module Enumerable
  # Just like `sort`, but tries to sort the same as the database does
  # using the proper Unicode collation algorithm. It's close.
  #
  # Differences in spacing, cases, and accents are less important than
  # character differences.
  #
  # "foo" < "fo p" o vs p is more important than the space difference
  # "Foo" < "fop" o vs p is more important than is case difference
  # "föo" < "fop" o vs p is more important than the accent difference
  #
  # It does not take a block.
  def sort_like_database(&block)
    if block_given?
      raise ArgumentError, "Does not accept a block"
    else
      # Sort by the database sort key. Two different strings can have the
      # same keys, if so sort just by its unicode sort key.
      sort_by { |v| [database_sort_key(v), v.unicode_sort_key] }
    end
  end

  # Just like `sort_by`, but it sorts like `sort_like_database`.
  def sort_by_like_database(&block)
    sort_by { |v|
      field = block.call(v)
      [database_sort_key(field), field.unicode_sort_key]
    }
  end

  # Sort by the unicode sort key after stripping out all spaces. This provides
  # a decent simulation of the Unicode collation algorithm and how it handles
  # spaces.
  private def database_sort_key(key)
    key.gsub(/\s+/,'').unicode_sort_key
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is any chance to update Ruby to 2.5.0, it comes with [`String#unicode_normalize`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-unicode_normalize). The latter will make the task way easier: all you need is to *normalize the string to decomposed form* before getting rid of non-letters. In the input we have 4 strings. In `qüia` there is *a combined diacritics*, in `'qü ic'` there is a composed character:

```
['quid', 'qüia', 'qu ib', 'qü ic'].map &:length
#⇒ [4, 5, 5, 5]
```

and, voilà:

```
['quid', 'qüia', 'qu ib', 'qü ic'].sort_by do |s|
  s.unicode_normalize(:nfd).gsub(/\P{L}+/, '')
end
#⇒ ["qüia", "qu ib", "qü ic", "quid"]
```

To sort case insensitive, `String#downcase` it inside a sorter:

```
["di Silva Fred", "diSilva Fred", "disílva Fred",
 "di Silva John", "diSilva John", "disílva John"].sort_by do |s|
  s.downcase.unicode_normalize(:nfd).gsub(/\P{L}+/, '')
end
#⇒ ["di Silva Fred", "diSilva Fred", "disílva Fred",
#   "di Silva John", "diSilva John", "disílva John"]
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer. This doesn't sort the example from UTS#10 correctly. It should be `["di Silva Fred", "diSilva Fred", "disílva Fred", "di Silva John", "diSilva John", "disílva John"]` but this produces `["diSilva Fred", "di Silva Fred", "di Silva John", "diSilva John", "disílva Fred", "disílva John"]`.

Comment: You did not say a word about you want it to be sorted case-insensitive. Updated an answer.

Comment: I need it sorted according to the Unicode collation algorithm in UTS#10 that is linked to in the question. I've put a more detailed example in the question to make it clear. This is a multi-pass algorithm which gives types of differences different weights; case difference is given a very low weight. If you throw `di silva fred` into the mix you'll see with your solution it jumps around because it sorts the same as `di Silva Fred`. A secondary sort on the unmodified key helps. `a.shuffle.sort_by { |s| [s.downcase.unicode_normalize(:nfd).gsub(/\P{L}+/, ''), s.unicode_normalize(:nfd)] }`